# How to Catch Errors from Apollo/GraphQL

Tags: error-handling, graphql, react-apollo, graphcool

I use graphCool as a backend, but **there is a bug** which won't be fixed any time soon.

Making a `delete` `mutation` on `File` schema **will always throw this error** (not a big deal):

"GraphQL error: Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Please contact us from the Console (https://console.graph.cool) or via email (support@graph.cool) and include your Request ID:"

**The call works, but I need to access the `update` function after the call and I can't because of the error.**

**Two solutions:** 
1. Catch the graphql error so I can reach `update:` function, how can I do this?
2. Update the store without using the `update:` function, how can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
_deleteImageFile = async () => {
    // THIS WORKS, BUT GET AN ERROR
    const socialPostId = this.props.socialPost.id
    // Tried to wrap the following in try catch without success
    await this.props.deleteImageFileMutation({
        variables: {
            id: this.props.socialPost.image.id
        }, //Error hits here "internal service error..."
        update: (store) => { //This is never run because of error
            console.log('this text will never log')
            const userId = localStorage.getItem(GC_USER_ID)
            const data = store.readQuery({query: ALL_SOCIAL_POSTS_QUERY, 
                variables: {
                    id: userId
            }})
            // Need to change the store here
            store.writeQuery({query: ALL_SOCIAL_POSTS_QUERY, data, 
                variables: {
                    id: userId
            }}).catch(res => { const errors = res.graphQLErrors; console.log(errors)})
            //The catch was an attempt to fix it
        }
    })
}
```

Reference Bug: https://github.com/graphcool/framework/issues/434

Answer (score 2):

You could try to pass down another dummy mutation and do that after the `deleteImageFileMutation` throws.

```
try {
  await this.props.deleteImageFileMutation ...
} catch (e) {
  // ...
} finally {
  await this.props.dummyMutation ...
}
```

Comment: Oh so like the dummy mutation wouldn't do anything but it would give me the chance to update you mean?